# overwrite .rst files during Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

Let us say that we have a document structure that looks like the following

```
.
|____src
| |____abc.py
|____docs
```

Now we generate documentation with the command:

```
sphinx-apidoc -F -o docs src
```

This generates several files within the `./docs/` folder that, *including* a `./docs/abc.rst`, which I can now build using a `make html` within the `./docs/` folder.

Now, after adding some additional function within `./src/abc.py` I want to rebuild the documentation. I try the same things and Sphinx says that the rest file is already present and as a result, it doesn't get updates. *I have to manually delete the relevant files before I can update the documentation.*

Now the question is, how do I do the entire process without having to resort to deleting the `.rst` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**sphinx-apidoc** has a `--force` option for overwriting files.

See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#sphinx-apidoc-manual-page.